# page.request differs from source url

Tags: asp.net

i write `"?id=32%31"` to Url.

but where `request["id"]==>321`

why?

Comment: `%31` is the URL-encoded form of the character `1`. Therefore, your request variable is indeed `321`. What did you expect?

Comment: Why are you writing %31 to the URL? If you are trying to delimit 2 values, just add more parameters. Ex: ?id1=31&id2=32

Comment: i encode ip and write to url. that % between the string

Comment: Then just put a . Ex: ?id=111.111.111.111

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing here is your web framework correctly URL decoding the parameters - %31 is the digit '1'